# is it view or join what I need for this mysql exersice

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I came across small task using mysql and mphpmyadmin, which I need to combine 2 tables records in one table, after each other... but also want the results to indicate the table that comes from, something like this:

table1: table name: "names1"

```
id code name  number
1  XA   Mike  101
2  DA   Stel  344
3  MB   Dan   434
4  TR   Tina  321
```

table2: table name:  "names2"

```
id code name number
1  DC   Man  121
2  QZ   Dan  989
3  VN   Was  912
```

What I need is to combine them in one table, select, view... any statement to use in my script... something like this:

```
tablename code name number
names1    XA   Mike  101
names1    DA   Stel  344
names1    MB   Dan   434
names1    TR   Tina  321
names2    DC   Man   121
names2    QZ   Dan   989
names2    VN   Was   912
```

Tried join and union, failed, do you advice to create a view? and how you would suggest to be done?

Comment: try `union` of 2 `select`

Comment: what is your mysql version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  code, name,  number, 'names1' as tablename from table1
union
select   code, name,  number, 'names2' as tablename from table2;
```

also look into the difference between union vs `union all` as it relates to dupes (in general for your other union like queries)

Comment: `union all` is much preferred to `union` because the latter incurs the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: yes union all worked and added Satty's suggestion I have first column says names1 then list all records as supposed to. thanks Satty :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine them in one *result set*, then you would use `union all` (as @Satty suggests).

However, if you want them in one table, then you can use `create table as`:

```
create table names as 
    select code, name, number from names1 union all
    select code, name, number from names2;
```

You could also create a view using the same logic, but the question explicitly says "one table".

Comment: thank you, union all worked for my case, but also used the 'name1' from Satty suggestion to have the additional column refer to the original table.. thakns

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to create a VIEW for this:

```
CREATE VIEW names3 AS 
(SELECT code, 
  name,  
  number, 
  'names1' as tablename 
  from names1)
UNION
(select code, 
  name,  
  number, 
  'names2' as tablename 
  from names2);
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64a648/1/0) is the fiddle.

Comment: thank you for the view setup, i would go for the union all as it worked for now